# R Calling a variable inside a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create an indicator index inside of a loop but can't figure out the correct syntax.

Outside of a loop I'd do something like this:

```
df1$flagVar <- 0
indicatorIndex <- which(df1$Sales > 0)
df1[indicatorIndex,'flagVar'] <- 1
```

Inside a loop I tried this:

```
for(i in variableNames){
     newVar <- paste(i,'_flag', sep = '')
     indIndex <- which(df1[df1[,i] > 0,])
     df1[,newVar] <- 0
     df1[indIndex,newVar] <- 1
}
```

but it's breaking with this error message:

```
Error in which(df1[df1[,i] > 0,]) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message should be self-explanatory since you obviously know how to use `which()`. Why do you want to loop it when you don't need to?

Comment: @RichardScriven: I have to repeat this process for ~ 20 variables.  I'm open to other suggestions if you don't think a loop is needed.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result?

Comment: Looks like an `ifelse(df1[,i] > 0, 1, 0)` would be appropriate here.

Comment: Or `as.numeric(df1[,i] > 0)` would do the same thing

Comment: @RichardScriven: this `as.numeric(df1[,i] > 0)` did it - thank you.